# Site Web Parts Sharepoint 2013

Tags: web-part

How can I restore the normal layout of web parts. (ie full width, left, right).  I am not seeing the full width.

Comment: While the question itself isn't really clear, based fro what I can get I would assume that your web parts got "smaller" because you use a different page layout? Not all the layouts include a full width area.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your full query. But assuming, you are trying to get different type of layout for your SharePoint page. SharePoint has different type [page layout and site template settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/About-page-layout-and-site-template-settings-1acbb881-269b-4e1b-86cc-8644bfffe40b) as its own features. You can use from those. Or you can create a [customized layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822368.aspx) of your own. And to built a customized layout you can use [Microsoft SharePoint Designer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint_Designer).